# Center blockquote on page but keep text left-aligned and mobile responsive

Tags: css

I created a simple page with Bootstrap and would like to have my blockquotes (including the left quotation mark added with a CSS pseudoselector) centered on while being mobile responsive.

Additionally, I tried setting the blockquote to have a width of 500px in CSS, and it made it look right on my laptop, but caused the quote text to go off the page on mobile rather than scaling down. So I removed the width declaration.

Here's my current CSS for the blockquote and corresponding quotation mark:

```
blockquote {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 3em auto;
  padding: 0.35em 40px;
  line-height: 1.45;
  position: relative;
  color: #383838;
}

blockquote p {
  font-size: 1em !important;
}

blockquote:before {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  content: "\201C";
  font-size: 3em;
  /* Element with abolute positioning is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor */
  position: absolute;
  /* Offsets from edges of element's containing block, ancestor to which element is relatively positioned */
  left: -3px; /* Negative moves it left */
  top: -13px; /* Negative moves it toward top */
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

blockquote cite {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged Bootstrap 4?

Comment: Re: 500px width, consider a percentage width, with a fixed max-width.  Something like width:80%;max-width:500px;  Some flavor of this will be appropriate and not require a media query for mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `display: inline-block;text-align: left;` to `blockquote` and also `text-align: center;` to `.jumbotron` in css:

```css
body {
  margin-top: 3em;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

img {
  width: 90%;
}

.panel img {
  height: 400px;
  width: auto;
}

.panel h4 {
  font-size: 10px;
}
.jumbotron {
  text-align: center;
}
.jumbotron blockquote {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 3em auto;
  padding: 0.35em 40px;
  line-height: 1.45;
  position: relative;
  color: #383838;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

blockquote p {
  font-size: 1em !important;
}

blockquote:before {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  content: "\201C";
  font-size: 3em;
  /* Element with abolute positioning is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor */
  position: absolute;
  /* Offsets from edges of element's containing block, ancestor to which element is relatively positioned */
  left: -3px; /* Negative moves it left */
  top: -13px; /* Negative moves it toward top */
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

blockquote cite {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  /* Bottom set to 3em to match margin above ul created by blockquote */
  margin: 0 auto 3em auto;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>David Hume</title>
  <!-- Ensures proper rendering and touch zooming -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Provides a responsive, fixed-width container. Needed as outermost wrapper in order for Bootstrap grid system to work correctly -->
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Big grey box for calling extra attention to content -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="text-center">
            <h1>David Hume</h1>
            <h4>Scottish Enlightenment Philosopher, Historian, Economist, Essayist</h4>
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="https://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/2015/09/03/BOB_Essay_Opener_WEBCrop/1920.jpg?1441298243" alt="Portrait of David Hume">
              <div class="caption">"Portrait of David Hume," 1754, by Allan Ramsay</div>
            </div>
          </div> <!-- End of text-center div -->

          <blockquote>
          <p>A wise man proportions his belief to the evidence.</p>
          <footer class="blockquote-footer"><cite>David Hume</cite></footer>
          </blockquote>

        </div> <!-- End of col-xs-12 div -->
      </div> <!-- End of row div -->

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
          <h4 class="text-center">A brief timeline in events of David Hume's life:</h4>
          <ul>
            <li><strong>1711</strong> – Born as David Home in Edinburgh, Scotland</li>
            <li><strong>1713</strong> – Father dies</li>
            <li><strong>1723</strong> – Enrolls at University of Edinburgh at the age of 12 (14 was typical)</li>
            <li><strong>1734</strong> – Changes surname to Hume</li>
            <li><strong>1739</strong> – Publishes Books 1 and 2 of <em>A Treatise on Human Nature</em></li>
            <li><strong>1748</strong> – Publishes <em>An Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding</em></li>
            <li><strong>1751</strong> – Publishes <em>An Enquiry Concerning the Principles of Morals</em></li>
            <li><strong>1776</strong> – Dies at the age of 65</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="text-center">Works</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row text-center">

            <div class="col-md-6">
            <h5>An Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding</h5>
            <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51RE8VsWyGL.jpg" alt="An Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding">
            <br><br>
            <h5>An Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding</h5>
            <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51RE8VsWyGL.jpg" alt="An Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
            <h5>Dialogues Concerning Natural Religion</h5>
            <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51RE8VsWyGL.jpg" alt="Dialogues Concerning Natural Religion">
            <br><br>
            <h5>An Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding</h5>
            <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51RE8VsWyGL.jpg" alt="An Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding">
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <blockquote>
            <p>Were it not for his infidel writings, every body would love him.</p>
            <footer class="blockquote-footer"><cite>James Boswell</cite></footer>
            </blockquote>

            <h4 class="text-center">Learn more on <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Hume" target="_blank">Wikipedia</a>.</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <footer class="text-center">
    <hr>
    <p>Written and coded by <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/natalie-cardot/" target="_blank">Natalie Cardot</a></p>
    </footer>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```